# Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PhoneInputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting an error  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PhoneInputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'. how can I solve this issue?

```
import React, {ForwardedRef} from 'react';
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2';
import 'react-phone-input-2/lib/bootstrap.css'


const FormikPhoneInput = React.forwardRef(
  ({ name, country, ...rest }: {name: string, country: string}, ref: React.ForwardedRef<any>) => (
    <PhoneInput {...rest} ref={ref} name={name}  />
  )
);


export default FormikPhoneInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to pass the inputProps as an object .

```
<PhoneInput {...rest} inputProps={{ ref }} name={name}  />
```